# Build SUMO without GUI

Tags: sumo

Is it possible to build SUMO without GUI i.e. without Fox toolkit (libfox)?

I don't really need it for my Docker image. I know from SUMO's build instructions (https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Installing/Linux_Build.html) that it is possible to do so by defining `-D FOX_CONFIG=` for cmake. However, when building version 1.2.0 (and possibly higher) the build fails on `make` as it still tries to look for `fx.h`.

**Edit (add build logs):**

In `sumo-1.2.0/build/cmake-build`, following is the output for:

1. `cmake ../..`

```
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: /home/sumo-1.2.0/build/cmake-build
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: /home/sumo-1.2.0
--
-- Platform:
--     Host: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64
--     Target: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64
--     CMake: 3.16.3
--     CMake generator: Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool: /usr/bin/make
--     Compiler: Clang 10.0.0
--
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.18")
-- Found Python: /usr/bin/python
-- Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
-- Found XercesC: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxerces-c.so (found version "3.2.2")
-- Found Proj: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so
-- Could NOT find Fox. GUI and threading will not be available. If it is installed, try to set the environment variables FOX_INCLUDE_DIR and FOX_LIBRARY.
-- Found Fox:
-- Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH X11_X11_LIB)
-- Found GDAL: /usr/lib/libgdal.so (found version "3.0.4")
-- Could NOT find suitable FFmpeg.
-- Could NOT find osgGA (missing: OSGGA_LIBRARY OSGGA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgViewer (missing: OSGVIEWER_LIBRARY OSGVIEWER_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgUtil (missing: OSGUTIL_LIBRARY OSGUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgDB (missing: OSGDB_LIBRARY OSGDB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgText (missing: OSGTEXT_LIBRARY OSGTEXT_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osg (missing: OSG_LIBRARY OSG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenThreads (missing: OPENTHREADS_LIBRARY OPENTHREADS_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenSceneGraph (missing: OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIBRARIES OPENSCENEGRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "3.4.0")
-- Could NOT find GL2PS (missing: GL2PS_LIBRARY GL2PS_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Found SWIG: /usr/bin/swig4.0 (found suitable version "4.0.1", minimum required is "3.0")
-- Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
CMake Warning at src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt:73 (message):
  ENABLE_JAVA_BINDINGS is set but Java or JNI was not found.


-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
CMake Warning at src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt:116 (message):
  ENABLE_PYTHON_BINDINGS is set but python libraries were not found.


-- Could NOT find Git (missing: GIT_EXECUTABLE)
-- Enabled features: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64 Clang 10.0.0 Release Proj GDAL SWIG
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sumo-1.2.0/build/cmake-build
r
```

2. `cmake -D CHECK_OPTIONAL_LIBS=OFF -D FOX_CONFIG= ../..`

```
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: /home/sumo-1.2.0/build/cmake-build
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: /home/sumo-1.2.0
--
-- Platform:
--     Host: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64
--     Target: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64
--     CMake: 3.16.3
--     CMake generator: Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool: /usr/bin/make
--     Compiler: Clang 10.0.0
--
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.18")
-- Found Python: /usr/bin/python
-- Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
-- Found XercesC: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxerces-c.so (found version "3.2.2")
-- Found Proj: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so
-- Could NOT find Fox. GUI and threading will not be available. If it is installed, try to set the environment variables FOX_INCLUDE_DIR and FOX_LIBRARY.
-- Found Fox:
-- Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH X11_X11_LIB)
-- Could NOT find Git (missing: GIT_EXECUTABLE)
-- Enabled features: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64 Clang 10.0.0 Release Proj
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sumo-1.2.0/build/cmake-build
```

3. `cmake -D FOX_CONFIG= ../..`

```
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: /home/sumo-1.2.0/build/cmake-build
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: /home/sumo-1.2.0
--
-- Platform:
--     Host: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64
--     Target: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64
--     CMake: 3.16.3
--     CMake generator: Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool: /usr/bin/make
--     Compiler: Clang 10.0.0
--
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.18")
-- Found Python: /usr/bin/python
-- Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
-- Found XercesC: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxerces-c.so (found version "3.2.2")
-- Found Proj: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so
-- Could NOT find Fox. GUI and threading will not be available. If it is installed, try to set the environment variables FOX_INCLUDE_DIR and FOX_LIBRARY.
-- Found Fox:
-- Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH X11_X11_LIB)
-- Found GDAL: /usr/lib/libgdal.so (found version "3.0.4")
-- Could NOT find suitable FFmpeg.
-- Could NOT find osgGA (missing: OSGGA_LIBRARY OSGGA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgViewer (missing: OSGVIEWER_LIBRARY OSGVIEWER_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgUtil (missing: OSGUTIL_LIBRARY OSGUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgDB (missing: OSGDB_LIBRARY OSGDB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgText (missing: OSGTEXT_LIBRARY OSGTEXT_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osg (missing: OSG_LIBRARY OSG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenThreads (missing: OPENTHREADS_LIBRARY OPENTHREADS_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenSceneGraph (missing: OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIBRARIES OPENSCENEGRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "3.4.0")
-- Could NOT find GL2PS (missing: GL2PS_LIBRARY GL2PS_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Found SWIG: /usr/bin/swig4.0 (found suitable version "4.0.1", minimum required is "3.0")
-- Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
CMake Warning at src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt:73 (message):
  ENABLE_JAVA_BINDINGS is set but Java or JNI was not found.


-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
CMake Warning at src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt:116 (message):
  ENABLE_PYTHON_BINDINGS is set but python libraries were not found.


-- Could NOT find Git (missing: GIT_EXECUTABLE)
-- Enabled features: Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64 Clang 10.0.0 Release Proj GDAL SWIG
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sumo-1.2.0/build/cmake-build
r
```

and same output for `make` as follows:

```
...
[ 12%] Linking CXX static library libutils_options.a
[ 12%] Built target utils_options
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/Shape.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/SUMOPolygon.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/PolygonDynamics.cpp.o
In file included from /home/sumo-1.2.0/src/utils/shapes/PolygonDynamics.cpp:24:
/home/sumo-1.2.0/src/foreign/rtree/SUMORTree.h:26:10: fatal error: 'fx.h' file not found
#include <fx.h>
         ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/build.make:89: src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/PolygonDynamics.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2973: src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

and following is the build log with

```
...
[ 12%] Linking CXX static library libutils_options.a
[ 12%] Built target utils_options
Scanning dependencies of target utils_shapes
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/Shape.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/SUMOPolygon.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/PolygonDynamics.cpp.o
In file included from /home/sumo-1.2.0/src/utils/shapes/PolygonDynamics.cpp:24:
/home/sumo-1.2.0/src/foreign/rtree/SUMORTree.h:26:10: fatal error: 'fx.h' file not found
#include <fx.h>
         ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/build.make:89: src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/PolygonDynamics.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2973: src/utils/shapes/CMakeFiles/utils_shapes.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Comment: It should work with the most recent sumo which has a CI build testing this. If you insist on using 1.2, can you post the precise error message?

Comment: @Michael, per your request, I have added the build logs to my question. Please take a look. I tried 3 ways for `cmake` but still get the same error.

Comment: The reason that I insist on 1.2.0 is because the latest version of VEINS (veins.car2x.org) i.e. 5.0 supports SUMO up to 1.2.0 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to install fox16-devel even if you don't need the GUI. A quick fix could be to remove the inclusion of SUMORTree.h from src/utils/shapes/PolygonDynamics.cpp, see https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/commit/09c5530b38085c6feb0283aba7b4113a74c9031a

Comment: Compiling with GUI is not really a big issue but I just wanted to keep my docker image as small as possible. Thank you.